# bs-dropdown in angular5 broken when using container="body"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I used the drop-down below, it was working properly. The only issue was it was adding scroll to responsive table designs.

Below is the example it was **before change**:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
    <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdownToggle>
        ...
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" class="list-dropdown-style Xpull-right fn-force-close-webuipop-on-a-click dropdown-menu">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example **after changes**:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body container="body">
    <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" dropdownToggle>
        ...
    </button>
    <ul *dropdownMenu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button" class="list-dropdown-style Xpull-right fn-force-close-webuipop-on-a-click dropdown-men the ">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

the only thing I added to the 2nd example is  **container="body"**.

I was expecting it to open the drop-down below the button on the button click, as it was working before. But, after the changes, it opens the drop-down list far left of its actual position.

Comment: Please give specific details around what is broken. It would also be helpful if you gave info around what you are trying to do and what the expectations were of that change.

Comment: Thank you DanielWStrimpel. I have updated details.